# What are the correct steps to set up django-cache-machine?

Tags: python, django, caching, django-cache-machine

I am new to Django and caching and is using Django 1.6.

I followed the instructions on django-cache-machine' page to install it.

1.pip install django-cache-machine

2.Add following to settings.py

```
CACHES = {
    'default': {
        'BACKEND': 'caching.backends.memcached.MemcachedCache',
        'LOCATION': 'localhost:11211',
        'PREFIX': 'wee:',
    },
}
```

3.Apply the changes on one of my models just as the minimal case in the instructions.

When I try to run server, it shows the following errors.

> django.core.cache.backends.base.InvalidCacheBackendError: Could not
>   find backend  'caching.backends.memcached.MemcachedCache': 'module'
>   object has no attribute ' CacheClass'

I previously installed johnny-cache but quickly removed it and then installed cache machine. I dont know if it is relevent. Memcached is also running.

Thanks in advance!

EDIT:

Just found that it is already mentioned in one issue in the Github page of the app.
https://github.com/jbalogh/django-cache-machine/issues/44

And a fix is pulled in. So I reinstall the github version.

```
pip install -e git://github.com/jbalogh/django-cache-machine.git#egg=django-cache-machine
```

Now it shows another error.

```
ImportError: No module named memcache
```

So I install another app called python-memcached. The server runs but no caching occurs.

I run python shell and the app works fine. So I think the problem is still django-cache-machine.

I guess django-cache-machine just not yet fully support Django 1.6.

If anyone knows how to get it work on Django 1.6+Python 2.7, please let me know.

Thanks again!

Comment: Ref the docs: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/cache/#memcached it looks like for BACKEND you should be using `'django.core.cache.backends.memcached.MemcachedCache'`. Seems consistent with the example here: https://github.com/jbalogh/django-cache-machine/blob/master/examples/cache_machine/settings.py

Comment: The example on github is using the backend I wrote above.
Also, shouldn't I use the custom backend provided by django-cache-machine instead of the stock one from Django?

Comment: have you installed memcache server?

Answer (score 1):

Just install memcach with:

```
  pip install python-memcached
```

That solved the problem for me!

Answer (score 0):

replace with this :

```
'BACKEND': 'django.core.cache.backends.locmem.LocMemCache',
```